# Spring cloud Angel.SR3 not working for config client

Tags: spring, configuration, spring-cloud

I have an application using spring cloud server and spring cloud client. The spring cloud server has this in POM:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>Angel.SR3</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

This version was upgraded from 1.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, it is good, but the problem happened for spring cloud client:

This is my current POM parent setting:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
```

with this version, the env variable can be auto injected from config service, but once I change that to Angel.SR3, the auto injection failed immediately, can not inject environment variable at all.

Is there something wrong from spring cloud here?

Answer (score 0):

After `1.0.0.RELEASE` you need to include `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config`.